# removing padding from amcharts tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using amcharts 4 in my angular project, and for tooltip I have written following lines of code:

```
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color('#fff');
series.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color('#000');
series.tooltip.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = `<div class="bg-dark text-white p-1 m-0">{date.formatDate('dd/MMM/yy')}</div>
<table class="m-0">
  <tr>
     <td><span class="fas fa-sm fa-circle text-primary"></span></td>
     <td>{flowCount}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>`;
```

The background fill and label is working fine but the padding is still there, how to remove the padding?

I want to remove the white space in tooltip.

[image]

Comment: Can you try `series.tooltip.label.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);`? Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the padding of the Label and not of the tooltip itself:

```
series.tooltip.label.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

See the docs for [`tooltip.label`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/#label_property) and [`lable.padding()`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#padding_method) for more information.

You also can use [`label.paddingBottom`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#paddingBottom_property), [`label.paddingLeft`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#paddingLeft_property), [`label.paddingRight`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#paddingRight_property), [`label.paddingTop`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#paddingTop_property) to set the values independently.